# Function to Check number

Tags: c++, function

I was wondering the most efficient way to check and see if a number that we grab from the user is between two numbers if not we will set it to a default value.

Example if we want to have them do a random guess of three numbers 1-25 but if they guess 27 20 10. They input a valid guess on two of the three.

So I can do something like:

```
if(g1 > 25 || g1 <0) {
     if(g1 >25) g1=25;
     if(g1 < 0) g1 =0;
}
```

then whole bunch more if statements to check input. I know I can use a function to check this but struggle. I thought through it and realize I can do like if g1 > 25 || g2> 25 || g3> 25 then I can call a function and run it through that. But I would still be using the same amount if and if else statements so this would not be the most efficient way.

Purposed idea

```
if (g1 >25 || g2> 25 || g3> 25) {
    guesstobig(g1,g2);
}
```

Then that would just equivalent the same amount in my function instead:

```
int guesstobig(int g1, int g2){
    if(g1>25) g1=25;
    if(g2 >25) g2=25;
    return g1, g2;
}
```

Comment: Can you write the code you think it is a struggle?

Comment: @lilezek, that has been added.

Comment: @TylerK _`return g1, g2;`_ You are aware what the comma operator does, no?

Comment: When your lower bound is 0 sometimes you will be better off eliminating the possibility entirely with an unsigned datatype.

Comment: Since C++17 you can find [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) in the Standard Library, defined in header `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
int clamp(int i)
{
    if(i<0)
        return 0;
    if(i>25)
        return 25;
    return i;
}

g1 = clamp(g1);
g2 = clamp(g2);
g3 = clamp(g3);
```

This way, you're checking once for every input if its below 0, and, if it's not, once if it is above 25.

Comment: Why not making that function more generic, taking lower and upper bound as parameters?

Comment: @user0042 The OP seems to have a very specific problem and this is all that is necessary. I trust that they'll be able to create a more generic version by themself if they need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isBetween(int upperBound, int lowerBound, int inputNumber) {
    return !(inputNumber > upperBound || inputNumber < lowerBound);
}
```

This function will return true if the `inputNumber` is between the `upperBound` and `lowerBound` inclusive.